# Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ of equation $y z-\ln z=x+y$

Tags: partial-derivative

Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ if the equation $y z-\ln z=x+y$ defines $z$ as a function of two independent variables $x$ and $y$ and the partial derivative exists?
How to solve this problem?
I do not know what to do after taking derivative with respect $z$ !

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2425555/108128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the implicit function $$F=yz-\log(z)-x-y=0$$ Differentiate
$$F'_z=y-\frac 1z$$ $$F'_y=z-1$$ Now, use the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dz}{dy}=-\frac{F'_y}{F'_z}$$